# UndefVarError: Normal not defined

Tags: julia, julia-jump, ijulia-notebook

At the moment of running the model the "Normal" says that it is not defined.  However, the idea is that it is a function that indicates random numbers of normal distribution with specific mean and variance.

The original code was made in Julia V0.5.2 but Julia 1.0.3 mentions that "Normal" does not exist.

```
n=5000;
t=15000;
lambda=0.8;
sigmae1=0.05;
sigmae2=0.1;
sigmaz= 0.013;
n_lambda= trunc(Int, lambda*n)
eshocks1=rand(Normal(0.0,sigmae1), n_lambda, t);
eshocks2=rand(Normal(0.0,sigmae2), n - n_lambda, t);
zshocks =rand(Normal(0.0, sigmaz),1, t);
```

> UndefVarError: Normal not defined
>
> Stacktrace:
>    [1] top-level scope at In[5]:21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add Distributions, then put

```
using Distributions
```

at the top of the code, for use with newer Julia versions. The later versions of Julia tend to have non-Base functions as optional modules that need to be added to the installation.